# Get working directory inside SSH client process from outside process

Tags: ssh, ps, lsof, pseudoterminal

I have SSH'd into a remote machine. I would like to get the current working directory (and ideally execute commands like `ls`) on that remote machine, but from outside this process.

Here are my processes

```
$ ps
49100 ttys001    0:00.21 -zsh
52134 ttys002    0:00.21 -zsh
52171 ttys002    0:00.05 ssh user@host.com
```

Terminal 2 (ttys002) is where I am currently SSH'd into a remote machine.

Is it possible to get the current working directory of the remote host from the client computer? ie without just typing `pwd` into Terminal 2.

If I run `lsof`, I can get the current working directory on the local machine of the process, but not the current working directory of the remote machine.

```
~ $ lsof -p 52171
COMMAND   PID    USER   FD      TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF                NODE NAME
ssh     52175   falky  cwd       DIR                1,4     2816              994619 /Users/falky
```

If this just isn't possible, would there be something I could do before SSHing into the remote machine that would allow me to do this? For example, could I set up a pseudo terminal? Or could I install something on the remote machine that sends a ping back to my local machine? Any advice/direction here would be helpful.

Comment: it is unclear what this means `current working directory of the remote host` .... it would have to be a specific process

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If this just isn't possible, would there be something I could do before SSHing into the remote machine that would allow me to do this?

You could start the ssh client in the "connection sharing mode":

```
ssh -M -S ~/.ssh/%r@%h:%p user@localhost
user@localhost's password:
...
user@localhost$ echo $$
5555
user@localhost$ cd /some/path
```

In another terminal:

```
ssh -S ~/.ssh/%r@%h:%p user@localhost
<no need to enter the password again>
user@localhost$ ls -l /proc/5555/cwd
<listing of /some/path>
```

Refer to the `ssh(1)` manpage for the [`-S`](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh#S) and [`-M`](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh#M) options, and to `ssh_config(1)` for the [`Control*`](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config#ControlMaster) config options.

Answer (score 1):

The only ways you can do that is either by

1. injecting the command into the local terminal with the `TIOCSTI` ioctl. This doesn't work on OpenBSD, and on Linux you need the `CAP_SYS_ADMIN` cap (i.e. be root) in order to use it on some other tty than the controlling tty of the calling process. You will already find a lot of examples of `TIOCSTI` use on this site.
2. manipulate the ssh client via `ptrace(2)`, e.g. via `gdb(1)` or other debugger, and inject the command into its encrypted channel. How to do this is highly dependent on the ssh client internals (for a ready to run example, you would need a ssh client compiled with debugging symbols). Just like with any other `ptrace(2)` solution, it will not work on other users' processes (or if the process has made itself undumpable), unless you have the `CAP_SYS_PTRACE` cap (i.e. you're root).
3. manipulate as per point 2. the process which controls the master side of the pseudo-tty the ssh client runs in, and have it write the command into the file descriptor of the pseudo-tty master. Because we have to write the data to a file descriptor, and not into some internal channel, it may be easier to give an example:

In a terminal:

```
$ tty
echo $PPID
6666
$ ssh localhost
localhost$ cd /tmp
localhost$
```

In another terminal, assuming that `PPID=6666` (the parent of the local shell) is the terminal emulator's process (not guaranteed!), and that you can correctly guess which file descriptor refers to the terminal of that shell (very hard to do when the terminal emulator is some kind of single-process multiplexer, like GNU screen):

```
$ pid=6666
$ ls -l /proc/$pid/fd
...

lrwx------ 1 xxx xxx 64 Oct 12 08:52 3 -> /dev/ptmx  # the pty master
...
$ grep flags /proc/$pid/fdinfo/3
flags:  0104002    # OK, it's opened in rw mode (2)
$ gdb -p $pid
...
(gdb) call write(3, "pwd\r", 4)
$1 = 4
(gdb) continue
Continuing.
...
```

If everything goes well, the `pwd` command will be run in the remote ssh.

If you're able to control the way ssh is started, you can make sure that the process which controls the pseudo-tty as per point 3. is some simple process and not some complicated multiplexer. On Linux, you can use the [`script(1)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/script.1.html) utility for that:

```
script /dev/null -c 'ssh user@host'
```

= file descriptor of the tty master inside the `script` process will **always** be 3 on Linux, and you don't have to bother is ssh is run directly or via `/bin/some/sh -c`.